# Getting sum of gridview cloumn using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am trying to get sum of grid-view column using for loop and put it in label

i have tried below code but it give me incorrect result

```
decimal total = 0;
protected void gridpandl_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < this.gridpandl.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        string proid = gridpandl.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
        string Purchase = GetPurchase(proid);
        this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text = Purchase;
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(Purchase);
        lbltotal.Text = Convert.ToString(total);

    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but this event is called foreach row. So, if you have two rows with a value of 10 for purchase you end up with a total of 40. I think you should move your loop after the DataBind() call not inside a RowDataBoud event

Comment: thanks you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RowDataBound event is called foreach row. So, if you have two rows with a value of 10 you will be called two times. The first time the total is correct, but the second time it keeps incrementing the total and you end up with a total of 40.

You should move your loop after the DataBind(), something like this....

```
this.gridpandl.DataSource = ... your get data source routine....
this.gridpandl.DataBind();
lbltotal.Text = SumRows();

....

private decimal SumRows()
{
    decimal total = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < this.gridpandl.Rows.Count; index++)
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text);
    return total
}
protected void gridpandl_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string proid = gridpandl.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
    this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text = GetPurchase(proid);
}
```